# How to name files to prevent web spider from fetching whole collection?

Tags: web-crawler

I want to store **+1M of product images** on file-system (ext4), so I can link to them from web. I use Ubuntu 16.04, NGINX 1.10, PHP 7 (in case you need it).

How should I name files to **prevent fetching my entire image collection** with web spider?

I know that I can not name all files sequentially, so I need to add chaos into naming. How?

Creating hash of 1.jpg would look randomly, but it is pretty easily discoverable that it is just hash...

Comment: if you make the files public they are well... public no matter what you name them.

Comment: There is difference between looking at 20 images which are on product page and fetching 1M files without having their URL (because I did not open product page).

Comment: What is preventing my spider from opening the product page? That's kinda how crawlers work.

Comment: Product pages will limit how many of them you can open per month per IP. Average visitors opens 10 pages per month, so something above that, lets say around 100.

After lets say 20 opened pages I will check whether client is Google bot (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553) and I will grant him exception.

Comment: I can verify Bing (0.4% visits) in same way (https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-verify-bingbot-3905dc26). Yahoo has 0.18%, Ask 0.05% visits so I will just ignore them and save bandwidth.

Comment: Just saying your reasoning is flawed, but you don't seem to really listen, which is fine.

Comment: I understand that I can not completely avoid it. But I can discourage it to such degree that it will became too expensive to perform (while not affecting normal users).

Comment: Everything you will do will become expensive for user not for machines. You are missing the point.

Comment: Not a single user will know about such limit. On other side, downloading 100/1.000.000 images per month will make spider useless. Try to open many Google results pages in short time...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict access to your images, I suggest looking at either Amazon S3 (to store your images) or Amazon CloudFront (you store your images on your own server).

Both allow you to restrict access to your images to a particular IP and expiration date. Thus, in PHP you can generate such a protected link to S3/CF and send it to the browser for each request.

Therefore, any browser / crawler needs to contact your webpage first before being able to retrieve the product images.

Here is some relevant documentation:

- Amazon S3: [Share an Object with Others](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)
- Amazon CloudFront: [Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Note that many other CDNs support signed / protected URLs as well.

---

Having said that, by far the easiest solution would be to add a salt to the hash that is unlikely to be guessed correctly. E.g. `sha1(1.jpg)` is much easier to recognize than `sha1(some-very-very-very-secret-key-1.jpg)`.

Comment: OK, so one way is hash with salt. While reading your answer, I realised that I could generate random `BIGINT` number and store path to file in DB with rest of product info.